VLAN Configuration without inter-vlan routing but with Internet access
I’m trying to set up multiple VLANs on my Cisco Catalyst 3850 switch and connect them to the internet using a TP-Link AX20/Asus RT-N12 router. I need this setup to have multiple isolated networks with different Ip ranges in a way that devices in each vlan cannot communicate with other vlans but they all have access to Internet.  However, the routers don't seem to support VLAN tagging (802.1Q), and I’m wondering if it’s possible to achieve this setup without needing a more advanced router.
My Current Setup:
Switch: Cisco Catalyst 3850 24T
VLANs created:
VLAN 10: 192.168.10.0/24
VLAN 20: 192.168.20.0/24
VLAN 30: 192.168.30.0/24

Each VLAN has an SVI configured with its respective gateway IP:
VLAN 10 SVI: 192.168.10.1
VLAN 20 SVI: 192.168.20.1
VLAN 30 SVI: 192.168.30.1

The routers do not support VLAN tagging or subinterfaces.
Its LAN IP is 192.168.1.1 (assigned manually) and is connected to a trunk/access port on the switch.
DHCP: DHCP pools are configured on the switch to assign IPs in the VLAN ranges automatically.
Problem:
Devices in each VLAN can communicate within their VLAN but they cannot access the internet.
I suspect the issue lies with the routers inability to recognize VLAN traffic. Since it doesn’t support VLAN tagging, it can only route traffic from a single subnet (VLAN 10 in this case).
just for test I even enabled Inter-VLAN routing on the switch using ip routing.
Question:

Is it possible to set up this configuration without replacing the router with a more advanced one that supports VLANs?
If yes, how can
I configure the switch and router to make it work?
If no, what would
be the simplest, cost-effective way to enable internet access for all
VLANs?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Let me
know if additional details are needed.
Thanks in advance!

crosspost: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86573/vlan-configuration-without-inter-vlan-routing-but-with-internet-access

Generally, you need the device acting as the default gateway for each VLAN's IP subnet to be able to act as a NAT (technically "NAPT", which Cisco calls "PAT") gateway for that subnet.
Your Cisco Catalyst 3850 is a so-called "layer 3 switch", meaning it has layer 3 (routing) capabilities as well as layer 2 (switching/bridging) capabilities, but a quick skim of the documentation makes it seem like it doesn't support NAT/NAPT/PAT, which seems to make it insufficient for your use case.
Since the Catalyst 3850's layer 3 capabilities don't meet your needs, you could use it as a simple layer 2 switch, still have it create separate VLANs, but skip the SVIs and disable its DHCP server features. Then use your existing separate NAT gateway wireless routers to each VLAN. So have your TP-Link AX20's LAN port to an untagged VLAN 10 access port on the Catalyst, and configure the AX20 to be the NAT gateway, default gateway, and DHCP server for the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet on that VLAN.
Similarly, connect your Asus RT-N12's LAN port to an untagged VLAN 20 access port on the Catalyst, and configure the RT-N12 to run the 192.168.20.0/24 subnet.
You'd of course need a third NAT gateway router to handle the third VLAN.
Another option you might look into is if either of your consumer NAT gateway boxes is supported by an aftermarket Linux (or other open source) router firmware distro, such as OpenWrt. Often Linux router firmware distros like OpenWrt support features that the factory firmware doesn't support, so maybe OpenWrt (or DD-WRT, or whatever) would support VLAN tagging/trunking on the LAN ports, and maybe even setting up separate NAT instances, one for each VLAN/subnet.

The Cisco as an intermediate router doesn't need NAT; it would be enough if the Asus or TP-Link router did it at the edge, as long as it can at least have static routes defined.

@grawity, yeah, but getting into that seemed like launching into a whole nother level of complexity that OP probably isn't ready for and doesn't have the equipment for, so I started with "Generally,…" as a big weasel-word.


Each VLAN has an SVI configured with its respective gateway IP:

Normally you wouldn't configure such IP addresses on a plain switch. The "gateway IP" needs to belong to the actual gateway (router) that'll be routing packets between the interfaces. If the Catalyst was supposed to only do switching, then it wouldn't have SVIs with IP addresses (beyond what is needed for management access).
However, your Catalyst switch actually seems to support IP routing between SVIs – only software (CPU) routing though; and since it's primarily a switch, I have doubts about the performance of its CPU – but it's still technically capable of doing it.
So you could try enabling the routing option if there is one, and defining ACLs or filter rules to block traffic between VLANs. For this to work behind your "main" router, that router needs to have 'static routes' defined for each subnet towards the Cisco switch.

Is it possible to set up this configuration without replacing the router with a more advanced one that supports VLANs?

There needs to be a router somewhere that has interfaces for all those networks (though not necessarily a single router; it could be several tiers).
As mentioned, your switch seems to be somewhat capable of being such a router.
If you can't use 802.1Q tagged VLANs, one fallback option is discrete physical Ethernet ports for each network – which, after all, is what VLANs emulate. For example, if your router at least supports untagged port-based LANs, you could configure each port for a different subnet and run 4 cables to untagged 'access' ports on the switch.
Note that the only VLAN-specific part of a router's configuration is defining the actual VLAN interfaces (SVIs) on top of a physical port. The rest – routing and filtering/firewall rules – is identical since it's a L3 matter.
There is also the last resort option: all IP subnets on a single VLAN. But this still requires a router that supports multiple IP subnets per interface, and doesn't provide true isolation – it's very easy to bypass the router if someone knows how to do it.

If no, what would be the simplest, cost-effective way to enable internet access for all VLANs?

Nearly any system that can run Linux or e.g. FreeBSD can act as a router with 802.1Q support. (I think all Ethernet interfaces support the required slightly larger L2MTU by now...)
So an old PC with Ethernet would do; an old wireless router or modem running OpenWrt would also work – although some 'wireless router' hardware might be problematic (some built-in switches use the same 802.1Q tagging to let the CPU distinguish between individual switch-ports); nearly all Mikrotik 'router' devices (with or without Wi-Fi) run firmware that has 802.1Q VLAN support.

In the switch can do ACLs it is as simple as to define 1 extra LAN for the LAN-side of the ISP facing router (with default gateway on the switch pointing to the ISP facing router) and have the switch route between all 4 of them. Then add an ACL on each of the 3 main vlans to deny traffic from the other 2.

Thanks @grawity for the detailed answer, I have enabled IP routing (without ACLs) to test but again VLANs won't get Internet and that as you said is because "For this to work behind your "main" router, that router needs to have 'static routes' defined for each subnet towards the Cisco switch", and for this I need to config some static routes on the router on each port of the router to point to a specific VLAN, and it limits num of VLANs to 4. But I will try this to see if it works.
I think my best option would be to switch to a router that supports VLANs and routing to different interfaces.

Generally yes, but if the Cisco switch was doing routing between VLANs, then the edge router wouldn't need to care about VLANs at all – it'd potentially need 4 routes defined, but that's not the same as 4 VLANs, as they all would be through the same "LAN" as far as it's concerned. (Better selection of IP subnets might allow those routes to be aggregated to a single /20 route.)
